# Using Chrome engine with AbcPDF and wait signal to render the pdf

Tags: abcpdf

I've changed recently from ABCPDF 10 to 12 to take advantage of npm and some good features of the chrome engine instead of Gecko's one.

With Gecko, you can initialise a variable to false ( the 'signal' ), and turns it to true when your doc is completely loaded. This works absolutely fine.

However, I cant find a way to do it with chrome engine because documentation says " pdf rendering starts when all resources are loaded ".

Does anyone encountered the same problem and found a way to get the same behavior with chrome than gecko engine ?

Thanks everyone